# iPhone and Android connected over same server

Tags: android, iphone, networking, middleware

I have written two apps, one for iPhone and one for android, both are fine but thus far I have given no thoughts into inter-operability. Ideally I would like both apps to be able to access a server and communicate with each other. I have no idea how to go about this, or indeed if it is even possbile. I would appreciate if you could point me in the direction of some resources that ight explain to me how to do this ?

As it stands, I have both apps working separately without connecting to a server, I would like to be able to connect them both to the same server and have both communicate. How do I do this?

Comment: Done! I didn't realise I was able to accept since I could not upvote! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are you trying to make the android app and the iphone app communicate between each other or just the 2 apps connect to the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of couse this is posible, as long as you don't use any platform specific communications.

Use JSON with a RESTFULL webservice and you are good to go.